# Entity Framework: Setting update timestamp

Tags: entity-framework

All of our database tables have UpdateUserID and UpdateTS.  I'd like to have this set if my entity has changes.  Is there a way I can have this update on the spot conditionally?

If I manually set UpdateTS in code, then it will say that my entity has changed and will always update the object.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an implementation of the other two ideas, with the following considerations

- Ensure that you either create proxies that automatically detect changes, or that you have manually detected changes, prior to the call to SaveChanges().  If not, the object state will be `EntityState.Unmodified`, and the last modified timestamp will not be updated.
- I have expanded the code to also set the last modified timestamp when the object is first created (`EntityState.Added`)

**The Code**

```
public interface IHasLastModified
{
    DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IHasLastModified
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {            
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
        {
            if (!entry.IsRelationship)
            {
                IHasLastModified lastModified = entry.Entity as IHasLastModified;
                if (lastModified != null)
                    lastModified.LastModified = now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: I use a similar solution, However I need to be able to handle proxyless entities as well (which are missed by the above code). I proposed a modification of the answer to support this, however it was rejected...

Comment: @Anders: Just post your own answer with the modification then.  You can reference my answer and point out how yours properly handles proxyless entities.

Answer (score 7):

I call this extension method before calling `context.SaveChanges()`:

```
public static void SetLastModified(this ObjectContext context, DateTime dateTime)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified))
    {
        if (!entry.IsRelationship)
        {
            IHasLastModified lastModified = entry.Entity as IHasLastModified;
            if (lastModified != null)
                lastModified.LastModified = now;
        }
    }
}
```

I can easily call this code, because I've wrapper the ObjectContext in a repository class. If you're using it bare, you can hook up the [`ObjectContext.SavingChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event to do something similar.

Comment: Trying to do the same as listed here but struggling with IHasLastModified.  only ever getting a null entry in lastModified.  Would you be able to post the code you have for this interface, or inform how you make your entities inherit from it?

Comment: I make sure my data object has a `DateTime` property called LastModified, and then implement the interface in a partial class (so code generation doesn't throw it away). Because the property is already there, there's no code to implement

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the solution proposed by @eric-j to work, it only set the dates when creating a new object but not when updating.

I found [this solution](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/set-created-and-modified-date-in-efcore.aspx) and modified it to look similar. Have tried out it, and it works like a charm.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    var entries = ChangeTracker
        .Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified);

    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        if (entry.Entity is IHasLastModified lastModified)
        {
            lastModified.LastModified = now;
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                lastModified.CreatedDate = now;
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```