# On updating a record in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using EF code first in my asp.net mvc project. I want an updated_at(DateTime) column in every table. So if I update a record, I want the column value to be set to current DateTime.

```
public abstract class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string password { get; set; }

    private DateTime _created_at;
    private DateTime _updated_at;

    public User()
    {
        _created_at = DateTime.Now;
        _updated_at = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public virtual DateTime created_at
    {
        get
        {
            return this._created_at;
        }
    }

    public virtual DateTime updated_at
    {
        get
        {
            return this._updated_at;
        }
    }
}
```

How Do I make that happen in EF without writing a TRIGGER in database directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097947/entity-framework-setting-update-timestamp

Comment: Your use of virtual does nothing in the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you `DbContext` constructor use the following:

```
public MyDbContext()
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.SavingChanges += ObjectContext_SavingChanges;
}

void ObjectContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Ensure that we are passed an ObjectContext
    ObjectContext context = sender as ObjectContext;
    if (context != null)
    {
        // Set DateTime to UTC when
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
            context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
            EntityState.Modified))
        {
            if (entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("_updated_at") != null)
            {
                dynamic entity = entry.Entity;
                entity._updated_at = DateTime.UtcNow;
                DateTime.SpecifyKind(entity._updated_at, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My _updated_at property is private. Can it be accessible from outside?

Comment: If you  have the model and context within the same assembly you can set `_update_at` as `internal` so that it can write it as well.

Comment: An interface would be a better approach.

Comment: it depends, maybe not all entities have that exact auditable field

Answer (score 0):

You should use an interface to define how you want to handle timestamping information in your classes. You can use this same technique for many different things.

```
public interface ITimeStampable
{
    DateTime created_at {get; set;}
    DateTime updated_at {get; set;}
}

public class User : ITimeStampable
{
    public User(){ 
        created_at = DateTime.Now;
        updated_at = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public DateTime created_at {get; set;}
    public DateTime updated_at {get; set;}
}

void ObjectContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var context = sender as ObjectContext;

   foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
       context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
       EntityState.Modified))
   {
       if (typeof(IAuditable).IsAssignableFrom(entry.Entity.GetType()))
                (entity as IAuditable).ChangeTS = DateTime.Now;
   }
}
```