# Entity Framework 6 SaveChanges() override not consistently detecting changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've extended a class in order to add a last modified timestamp to a record if there are material changes being made to it.  This was done with code similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097947/entity-framework-setting-update-timestamp).

Here's my problem.  `SaveChanges()` is firing for both changes, but the second one isn't getting into the loop: no objects are detected as needing changes.

However, the record *does* get updated by EF through the base.SaveChanges() call.

Here's the extension to MasterTable:

```
namespace AuditTestEF
{
    public interface IHasAuditing
    {
        DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
        int LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MasterTable : IHasAuditing
    {
    }

    public class AuditTestEntitiesWithAuditing : AuditTestEntities
    {
        public int TestingUserIs = 1;

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in (this as IObjectContextAdapter)
                .ObjectContext
                .ObjectStateManager
                .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
            {
                // This loop is entered the first time, but not the second
                if (entry.IsRelationship) continue;

                var lastModified = entry.Entity as IHasAuditing;
                if (lastModified == null) continue;

                lastModified.LastModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                lastModified.LastModifiedBy = TestingUserIs;
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the test harness:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    MasterTable mtOriginal;
    using (var audit = new AuditTestEntitiesWithAuditing())
    {
        var message = "Hello";
        audit.TestingUserIs = 1;
        mtOriginal = new MasterTable {TextField = message};
        audit.MasterTable.Add(mtOriginal);
        audit.SaveChanges();
        // This test passes, TestingUser is set in the override
        Assert.IsTrue(mtOriginal.LastModifiedBy == audit.TestingUserIs);    
    }

    using (var audit = new AuditTestEntitiesWithAuditing())
    {
        var mt = audit.MasterTable.Find(mtOriginal.MasterTableId);
        mt.TextField = "Goodbye";
        audit.TestingUserIs = 4;
        audit.SaveChanges();
        // This test fails, the record is written with "Goodbye" but
        // GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified) has no entries.
        Assert.IsTrue(mt.LastModifiedBy == audit.TestingUserIs);            
    }
}
```

There's no other code.  There's no weird turning off/on the entity tracking or anything.  WYSIWYG.

What am I missing?  How is the clearly modified object being missed by the check for Modified?

Answer (score 1):

Annnd... answered my own question, of course, after talking to the duck.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
```

This fixes everything.  Thank you for your attention, I hope this helps someone else.